# CMake on Windows requires Administrator privileges

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, cmake

ALL,

I installed CMake on my Windows 7 laptop, but when trying to run and generate the solution files for MSVC 2010, I found it requires the "Administrator" privileges.

Why? Is there a way to run as a normal user?

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you try to create the build directory? Does this location require admin privileges? Normally CMake runs fine as a normal user.

Comment: @oLen, c:\program Files\CMake\bin. I guess it is the default place for CMake.

Comment: I meant the build directory for your project

Comment: @oLen, yes, that's what I meant. The files are generated inside there and then I can't even open MSVC as a regular user and build it.

Comment: Well, normally you would rather choose another directory for that, f.i. try a folder named "build" at the same location as your CMakeLists.txt.